# Cannot delete a Mongo document using mutation with Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I am having trouble deleting a MongoDB document using Apollo Client. I don't think my query syntax is the cause because I tested the query in Graphiql and it works fine. This is the error I am getting:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500

Call Stack
new ApolloError
node_modules/@apollo/client/errors/index.js (26:0)
Object.error
node_modules/@apollo/client/core/QueryManager.js (127:0)
notifySubscription
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:0)
onNotify
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:0)
SubscriptionObserver.error
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:0)
eval
node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/iteration.js (4:48)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
iterateObserversSafely
node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/iteration.js (4:0)
Object.error
node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/observables/Concast.js (35:42)
notifySubscription
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (140:0)
onNotify
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (179:0)
SubscriptionObserver.error
node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js (240:0)
eval
node_modules/@apollo/client/link/http/createHttpLink.js (110:0)
```

This is my code for the back end:

```
const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Company',
  fields: () => ({
    _id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(parentValue, args) {
        return User.findUsers(parentValue._id);
      },
    },
  }),
});

const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Mutation',
  fields: {
    deleteCompany: {
      type: CompanyType,
      args: { _id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) } },
      resolve(parentValue, { _id }) {
        return Company.remove({ _id }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
      },
    },
  },
});
```

This is my code for my React frontend

```
import React from 'react';
import { gql, useMutation } from '@apollo/client';

const DELETE_COMPANY = gql`
  mutation DeleteCompany($id: String!) {
    deleteCompany(_id: $id) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;

const CompanyList = () => {
  const { loading: loadingList, error: errorList, data: dataList } = useQuery(
    COMPANY_LIST
  );
  const [
    deleteCompany,
    { loading: loadingDelete, error: errorDelete, data: dataDelete },
  ] = useMutation(DELETE_COMPANY);

  const renderCompanies = () =>
    dataList.companies.map((company) => (
      <li key={company._id}>
        {company.name}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            deleteCompany({ variables: { _id: company._id } });
          }}
        >
          delete
        </button>
      </li>
    ));

  return (
    <div>
      {loadingList || loadingDelete ? <h1>Loading...</h1> : renderCompanies()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: check network request - _id not passed ... as string?

Comment: you need to change GraphQLObjectType to GraphQLInputObjectType for type passed inside mutations.